# Send hidden parameters through window object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code which opens the link in a new tab of the browser and its work fine.

```
window.open(
                'actionName?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value,
                '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
        );
```

Is it possible to send hidden parameter through it?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18264534/2417602

Comment: Did you try with localStorage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Variables to a new page without query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264489/passing-variables-to-a-new-page-without-query-string)

Comment: I not yet tried it through localStorage. I will try it after complete understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just save reference on window:

```
var win = window.open(url, name, params);
win['yourHiddenValues']={};
```

and you can use it on opened tab/window:

```
$(document).ready(x=> console.log(this['yourHiddenValues'])); //exists
```